# What's the best way to create a text-and-image link in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

**Question:**

I want to create a hyperlink with both text and a leading or trailing icon. This can be accomplished in at least two ways:

- With CSS setting a background-image property
- By creating a ASP.NET Html helper that generates an anchor tag followed by an image tag.

Are there more?

I'm guessing this is a problem that has been solved a million times, and there might be a best practice. I see negative and positive sides of both approaches, and I'd like some input from you guys.

**Metaquestion:**

Both here and on programmes.stackexchange I get the warning "your question appears subjective and is likely to be closed". Where do one ask subjective questions nowadays?

Comment: Ask your meta questions on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the icon content? i.e. does it add (not duplicate) meaning to the document?

If so, it is content and should be an `<img>` element with a suitable alt attribute.

If it decorative? Then CSS is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Good call. In my case I feel it's borderline: It's what Microsoft names a "progressive disclosure chevron" for a link with the text "show additional data". So it adds the information of "the additional data will be loaded in-place and not as a popup or in a new window"

Comment: @Nilzor, so it isn't content - it's visualized metadata. I'd go for CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I would give this anchor a padding-left and set image as non-repeating background.

Here is jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDPnH/

Comment: One issue with this example in my specific case: The text height is smaller than the image height, resulting in a cropped image. Any suggestion on how to solve that without changing to block mode display? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDPnH/7/

Comment: Well, you can use "inline-block" to set height of span: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDPnH/9/ Notice "line-height" if you want to align text vertically.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never heard of "inline-block" for some reason... I will use your answer in my specific case, but keeping Quentin's answer as accepted, as it gives rationale to on a general level.